# How to change your Local IP?

Tags: networking, server, 13.10, ip

While I order a hp server for my Ubuntu server, I am currently temporarily using my laptop as a server instead. I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and other programs like Webmin, etc, etc while being connected to my router through wi-fi. Additionally, through a wi-fi connection, I have hosted numerous websites, game servers and an ftp server.

The issue is that when I try to connect the laptop to the same router through ethernet, the local ip changes. This means that no services, such as Webmin, work locally or publicly. When I go back to using wi-fi, the issue is solved, however, because the wi-fi connection cannot maintain the traffic to and from the server, I need to use ethernet connection to keep up with the demand.

I have portforwarded the ports I use from my wi-fi local ip to my ethernet local ip but I have no luck so far since the problem is on the local side, not from local to public.

My question is, how can I configure my services to the new IP?

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#NetworkManager#auto wlan0
#NetworkManager#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#NetworkManager#        wpa-ssid routername
#NetworkManager#        wpa-psk  routerpassword
```

The result of ip ad is:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1c:23:3a:24:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.***.***/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.***.***/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21c:23ff:fe3a:24db/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:19:d2:03:0c:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::219:d2ff:fe03:cf8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip r
default via 192.168.***.*** dev eth0  proto static
192.168.***.***/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.***.***  metric 1

$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off
        Supports Wake-on: g
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
        Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Why do I see #NetworkManager - that is not default on a server install - or are you using a GUI?

Comment: Yes, I installed the unity package so that I can use the internet when I need to access webmin, phpmyadmin, etc from the server itself without having to use a different computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you need a CLI method:

Use your favourite editor to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` with root permissions.

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

(lines starting with `#` are just comments, they are not effective, you can leave them as they are, you also keep the lines with `lo` as they are)

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.100           # use the address you really want
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.254           # use the address of your router
```

You will have to restart the interface `sudo ifdown eth0` (may throw an error, ignore that), then `sudo ifup etho` - you can check if the settings are effective with `ip ad`.

For a detailed outline see

[Ubuntu Server Guide - chapter networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)

Comment: Hi, my interfaces file has a different layout than the one shown in your comment. Mine looks like this:
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#NetworkManager#auto wlan0
#NetworkManager#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#NetworkManager#        wpa-ssid routernamehere
#NetworkManager#        wpa-psk  routerpasswordhere

Comment: @user251124 those are only comments, ignore them)

Comment: No luck so far. I replaced the auto lo etcetcetc with what you suggested, however, it still doesn't work. Just to clarift, the address I really want is the server's local ip and "the adderss of your router" is the local ip of the router or the wi-fi ip?

Comment: @user251124 see my changed answer please.

Comment: @guntbert This would work fine if the address is within the LAN address range allocated in the router. It would be far more effective to use a DHCP reservation in the router via MAC address for the Ethernet connection and run the port-forwarding to that LAN IP address.

Comment: Hi, I changed the file again, however, when typing in sudo ifdown eth0, I get the response:
`ifdown: interface eth0 not configured`
and when I type sudo ifup eth0:
`Not enough information: "dev" arguement is required."
Failed to bring up eth0.`

Thank you, I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @user251124, strange . please make sure that your machine is connected to the wired network and edit your question with the output of `ip ad`, `ip r` and `ethtool eth0` (you don't need "<code>" tags,  just select the complete code and press `CTRL K`)

Comment: I am having some very weird issues. I connect to the server through putty and upon checking back to the server, the cursor and the wallpaper were present but nothing else. Upon restarting the server, it took a very long time to do networking configuration, after which, it gave up and loaded up properly- with no internet access. In console, I tried to carry out the ifconfig command which yielded in no eth0 results and upon restarting the networking service, the console froze and everything else went white.I could select the console lines or go to file, etc, however, couldnt type.tryingtorestart

Comment: ifconfig returns

lo link ....
   inet addr:127.0.0.1 ....
   ...

Comment: I managed to fix the aforementioned internet issues by reverting the interfaces file. Any ideas how to fix the issue with the internet not working?

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I managed to fix it by using your steps but replacing the "ip you want here" with the wi-fi ip, restarting the networking service. Thank you very much for everyone's time. Cheers

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks. This worked like a charm in my set up and saved me headaches.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special loopback address (127.0.0.1) that always points to your own computer. If you have Webmin (I'm not familiar with this program) listening on port 8080 on your computer, you can just go to 127.0.0.1:8080.

Edit: My bad. I was under the impression that you wanted to access the services from your own computer.

Comment: He wants access from outside his LAN.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought he meant from his own computer. But wouldn't the public IP address stay the same while the private IP address changes (a change in router port-forwarding, then)?

Comment: Yes, for the public address, but no for the forwarding (done on the router).

Comment: @saiarcot895 Just FYI - Webmin listens on port 10000 `https://localhost:10000`

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the infrastructure to set Local IP has shifted to Netplan

[Go to this link for details how to configure IP Address with Netplan on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)!

Briefly, you need to modify the relevant netplan network configuration file within /etc/netplan/ directory as follows:

`network:
    ethernets:
        enp2s0:                 #Your network interface
            addresses:
            - 192.168.0.100/24  #Change to your required IP
            dhcp4: false
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.1.1
                search: []
    version: 2`